# Cannot convert value of type 'String' to expected argument type 'DefaultStringInterpolation'

Tags: swift5

I upgraded my swift 4.2 application to Swift 5 and I get this error. Does anyone know how to fix?

File using: GMStepper.swift

**Error: Cannot convert value of type 'String' to expected argument type 'DefaultStringInterpolation'**

```
if self.showIntegerIfDoubleIsInteger && floor(self.value) == self.value {
            label.text = String(stringInterpolation: "\(Int(self.value))\(self.suffixString)")
        } else {
            label.text = String(stringInterpolation: "\(Int(self.value))\(self.suffixString)")
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

You should do like this :

```
if self.showIntegerIfDoubleIsInteger && floor(self.value) == self.value {
        let intValue =  Int(self.value)
        label.text = String(stringInterpolation: "\(intValue)\(self.suffixString)")
    } else {
        let intValue =  Int(self.value)
        label.text = String(stringInterpolation: "\(intValue))\(self.suffixString)")
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should not call `String.init(stringInterpolation:)` directly.

[`init(stringInterpolation:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/string/3129035-init)

> ### Discussion
>
> Do not call this initializer directly. It is used by the compiler when you create a string using string interpolation. Instead,
>   use string interpolation to create a new string by including values,
>   literals, variables, or expressions enclosed in parentheses, prefixed
>   by a backslash (`\(…)`).

Why don't you simply write your code as:

```
    if self.showIntegerIfDoubleIsInteger && floor(self.value) == self.value {
        label.text = "\(Int(self.value))\(self.suffixString)"
    } else {
        label.text = "\(Int(self.value))\(self.suffixString)"
    }
```